# Explicit Conversion Function

Tags: javascript

```
var integers = parseInt("0x10");
console.log(integers);
```

ParseInt() function is used to convert string value to integers. ParseInt() return 0 if the string does not begin with integers.

The answer of above code is: 16. 
i want to find out how is it giving an output of 16 rather than 0.

Comment: by the way, you don't need to parse such datum if coded literaly: `0x10 + 6 == 22`

Answer (score 0):

From [parseInt() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

> If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:
>
> - If the string begins with `"0x"`, the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)